# Patch request not patching - 403 returned - django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm trying to test an API endpoint with a patch request to ensure it works.

I'm using `APILiveServerTestCase` but can't seem to get the permissions required to patch the item. I created one user (`adminuser`) who is a superadmin with access to everything and all permissions.

My test case looks like this:

```
class FutureVehicleURLTest(APILiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Setup users and some vehicle data we can query against
        management.call_command("create_users_and_vehicle_data", verbosity=0)
        self.user = UserFactory()
        self.admin_user = User.objects.get(username="adminuser")
        self.future_vehicle = f.FutureVehicleFactory(
            user=self.user,
            last_updated_by=self.user,
        )
        self.vehicle = f.VehicleFactory(
            user=self.user,
            created_by=self.user,
            modified_by=self.user,
        )
        self.url = reverse("FutureVehicles-list")
        self.full_url = self.live_server_url + self.url
        time = str(datetime.now())
        self.form_data = {
            "signature": "TT",
            "purchasing": True,
            "confirmed_at": time,
        }
```

I've tried this test a number of different ways - all giving the same result (403).

I have setup the python debugger in the test, and I have tried actually going to `http://localhost:xxxxx/admin/` in the browser and logging in manually with any user but the page just refreshes when I click to login and I never get 'logged in' to see the admin. I'm not sure if that's because it doesn't completely work from within a debugger like that or not.

My test looks like this (using the Requests library):

```
    def test_patch_request_updates_object(self):
        data_dict = {
            "signature": "TT",
            "purchasing": "true",
            "confirmed_at": datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"),
        }
        url = self.full_url + str(self.future_vehicle.id) + "/"
        client = requests.Session()
        client.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(self.admin_user.username, "test")
        client.headers.update({"x-test": "true"})
        response = client.get(self.live_server_url + "/admin/")
        csrftoken = response.cookies["csrftoken"]
        # interact with the api
        response = client.patch(
            url,
            data=json.dumps(data_dict),
            cookies=response.cookies,
            headers={
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                "X-CSRFTOKEN": csrftoken,
            },
        )
        # RESPONSE GIVES 403 PERMISSION DENIED
        fte_future_vehicle = FutureVehicle.objects.filter(
            id=self.future_vehicle.id
        ).first()
        # THIS ERRORS WITH '' not equal to 'TT'
        self.assertEqual(fte_future_vehicle.signature, "TT")
```

I have tried it very similarly to [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apirequestfactory) using `APIRequestFactory`
and forcing authentication:

```
    def test_patch_request_updates_object(self):
        data_dict = {
            "signature": "TT",
            "purchasing": "true",
            "confirmed_at": datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"),
        }
        url = self.full_url + str(self.future_vehicle.id) + "/"
        api_req_factory = APIRequestFactory()
        view = FutureVehicleViewSet.as_view({"patch": "partial_update"})
        api_request = api_req_factory.patch(
            url, json.dumps(data_dict), content_type="application/json"
        )
        force_authenticate(api_request, self.admin_user)
        response = view(api_request, pk=self.future_assignment.id)
        fte_future_assignment = FutureVehicle.objects.filter(
            id=self.future_assignment.id
        ).first()
        self.assertEqual(fte_future_assignment.signature, "TT")
```

If I enter the debugger to look at the responses, it's always a `403`.

The `viewset` itself is very simple:

```
class FutureVehicleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FutureVehicleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = FutureVehicle.exclude_denied.all()
        user_id = self.request.query_params.get("user_id", None)
        if user_id:
            queryset = queryset.filter(user_id=user_id)
        return queryset
```

The serializer is just as basic as it gets - it's just the `FutureVehicle` model and all fields.

I just can't figure out why my user won't login - or if maybe I'm doing something wrong in my attempts to patch?

I'm pretty new to Django Rest Framework in general, so any guidances is helpful!

Edit to add - my DRF Settings look like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination",
    "DATETIME_FORMAT": "%m/%d/%Y - %I:%M:%S %p",
    "DATE_INPUT_FORMATS": ["%Y-%m-%d"],
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        # Enabling this it will require Django Session (Including CSRF)
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication"
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        # Globally only allow IsAuthenticated users access to API Endpoints
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"
    ],
}
```

I'm certain `adminuser` is the user we wish to login - if I go into the debugger and check the users, they exist as a user. During creation, any user created has a password set to 'test'.

Comment: if you can't login to admin, that user may not exist or is a super user. could also be an issue with your AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES have a look in settings and post what you have there

Comment: Hi @Dap; I know the user exists as a super user - I can see them in the `User` list when I query for them in debugger.  Additionally - I triple checked the data creation - they are marked as `is_superuser`; I've added the DRF settings.

Comment: Are you able to share any other details from the response (like the message sent back). Also can you confirm that the user has `is_active` as true?

Comment: I can confirm the user `is_active`; When I use the `request.Sessions` method, it appears the message sent back is `"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided"`, which I think explains things - not sure how I missed that before... now to figure out how to include those I guess (I have authenticated the user with `client.auth`)

Comment: Try to use `client.headers.update` with the headers found on your `client.patch` call

Comment: You have to create user in setup of tests, when django runs tests he creates a new database

Comment: did you try adding 
allowed_methods = ['PATCH']
on the Viewset?

Comment: Before testing a bunch of codes in python, it's better to check it with postman and see if you again get 403 error, its server side and you have to check permissions from server. I suppose you should open everything in server for just a second for test purpose, and see if it's ok or return 403 again, and then go through your code.

Comment: Did you have a chance to use the approach I detailed below?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Recommended Solution

The test you have written is also testing the Django framework logic (ie: Django admin login). I recommend testing your own functionality, which occurs *after* login to the Django admin. Django's testing framework offers a helper for logging into the admin, `client.login`. This allows you to focus on testing your own business logic/not need to maintain internal django authentication business logic tests, which may change release to release.

```py
from django.test import TestCase, Client


def TestCase():
   client.login(username=self.username, password=self.password)
```

## Alternative Solution

However, if you *must* replicate and manage the business logic of what `client.login` is doing, here's some of the business logic from Django:

```py
    def login(self, **credentials):
        """
        Set the Factory to appear as if it has successfully logged into a site.
        Return True if login is possible or False if the provided credentials
        are incorrect.
        """
        from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
        user = authenticate(**credentials)
        if user:
            self._login(user)
            return True
        return False

    def force_login(self, user, backend=None):
        def get_backend():
            from django.contrib.auth import load_backend
            for backend_path in settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS:
                backend = load_backend(backend_path)
                if hasattr(backend, 'get_user'):
                    return backend_path

        if backend is None:
            backend = get_backend()
        user.backend = backend
        self._login(user, backend)

    def _login(self, user, backend=None):
        from django.contrib.auth import login

        # Create a fake request to store login details.
        request = HttpRequest()
        if self.session:
            request.session = self.session
        else:
            engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
            request.session = engine.SessionStore()
        login(request, user, backend)
        # Save the session values.
        request.session.save()
        # Set the cookie to represent the session.
        session_cookie = settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME
        self.cookies[session_cookie] = request.session.session_key
        cookie_data = {
            'max-age': None,
            'path': '/',
            'domain': settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
            'secure': settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE or None,
            'expires': None,
        }
        self.cookies[session_cookie].update(cookie_data)
```

## References:

Django client.login: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/test/client.py#L596-L646

Comment: I accepted this as the answer. I'm not sure what wasn't working to begin with - because I had tried the `client.login()` method, but I must have had something else goofing it up and gotten rid of the bad code. It started working with that `client.login()` so that appears to be the solution. Thank you for the detailed explanations!